# On a browser, sessionStorage in Safari's Private Browsing does not work the same as Chrome's Incognito Mode and Firefox's Private Window?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, session-storage

It seems that for `sessionStorage`, it works differently on Chrome's Incognito Mode vs Safari's Private Browsing and Firefox's Private Window?  I can find something on http://www.webdirections.org/blog/webstorage-persistent-client-side-data-storage/ but it doesn't say that Safari's Private Browsing will throw an exception.

The following is how I opened "Private Browsing":

1. On Safari on Mac, click "Safari -> Private Browsing" on the menu bar
2. On Chrome, use "File -> New Incognito Window"
3. On Firefox, use "File -> New Private Window"

and on Safari, `sessionStorage` does not work, and if I do the following in the console:

```
> sessionStorage["foo"] = 123.4
Error: QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22

> sessionStorage["foo"] 
undefined
```

but on Chrome or Firefox, `sessionStorage` works as usual (as non-private browsing).  Is the above accurate as far as `sessionStorage` is concerned?

Comment: On a related note, you might want to file a bug / feature request to Apple about this particular behavior if you wished it to behave like the other browsers. But first check https://openradar.appspot.com/page/1 if it's already filed, and if not, then file bug to Apple and file a copy to OpenRadar for public tracking. Don't like how Apple does not make their bug tracker publicly viewable by all.

Comment: ts 2017 now , has anything changed in regards to private browsing mode (incognito)

Comment: @NigelFds It looks like it has. as of version 11.0.2 Safari's Private Browsing now acts the same as Chrome's Incog and Firefox' Private Browsing - Storage is usable. Saying if it persists between tabs or not is irrelevant as sessionStorage is for that tab only.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your assessment is practically accurate:

- Safari will just use a quota of `0` in private mode, so all attempts to set a value will fail. This is kinda OK according to the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space), as the spec does not mandate a minimum space requirement.
- Chrome and Firefox still allow you to use storage, however private storage is independent from non-private, i.e. setting an item in private mode will not reflect back into non-private mode (important for `localStorage` only).

Please note that other browsers are also free to throw `QuotaExceededError` exceptions at any given time, should you go over the quota.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by loading the following script on my layout: <https://gist.github.com/engelfrost/fd707819658f72b42f55 >? It checks if localStorage can be used and if not, it creates an alternative which works the same way. Hope this helps

Comment: @BogdanMates except it doesn't persist anything which renders localStorage useless.

Comment: @Esben Skov Pedersen, how exactly do you expect data to persist in private browsing mode? It would be violation of privacy

Comment: @KirillSlatin It could have the same semantics as cookies in chrome incognito. Starting with a clean slate and deleted after session is closed. Session storage could work exactly the same way as non-private mode with no violation of privacy.

Comment: This answer has irrelevant information about localStorage that makes it confusing and misleading

Comment: This answer no longer appears to be true with the newer versions of Safari. SessionStorage seems to work while private browsing with Safari.

Comment: SessionStorage no longer works with latest version of Chrome

Answer (score 6):

Safari latest version (Version 12.0) already have access to sessionStorage without any issue in incognito mode.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Safari Pivate mode supports localstorage and SessionStorage.

[image]