# Web Storage (sessionStorage and localStorage) in private browsing mode (incognito)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage, web-storage

**BACKGROUND**

The HTML5 Web Storage feature in modern browsers is accessed through Javascript commands such as:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("username", "John");
localStorage.setItem("username", "John")
```

The site [*Can I use*](https://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) indicates that browser support is near 90%. **However**, in the "Known Issues" tab, *Can I use* says:

> In private browsing mode, Safari, iOS Safari and the Android browsers do not support setting localStorage.

**MY QUESTION**

In private browsing mode, do Safari, iOS Safari and the Android browsers still support sessionStorage?

Comment: I was looking for an official answer not just a test of one browser.  This is unfortunate since sessionStorage, as the name implies, should be allowed in private browsing mode.

Comment: It's disabled with some settings in some browsers.
A great work-around available in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607724/ios-safari-private-browsing-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-support/43670472#43670472

See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159301/quotaexceedederror-dom-exception-22-an-attempt-was-made-to-add-something-to-st

Comment: Its 2017 now , has anything changed in regards to private browsing mode (incognito) ?

Answer (score 9):

Android and chrome I believe allow you to access old keys in session storage, but not write to it. I know that Safari will not allow any use of session or local storage.

[similar so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860098/on-a-browser-sessionstorage-in-safaris-private-browsing-does-not-work-the-same)

Comment: what about cookies? would that allow saving just across page refreshes?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper the discussion is beyond Cookies.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper I tested this in FF and cookies work(kept) in private mood across tabs

Answer (score 1):

Chrome will support **localStorage** and **sessionStorage** in private window.

Comment: but when? could you provide an official link where a such thing is stated? so far not yet supported (jan 2021)