# LocalStorage in chrome Incognito Mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, web-storage, incognito-mode

So In my Angular 1.5 application, I want to retain data on page load also,

So I am using `$window.localStorage`.

I am reading some value from `localStorage` and it also works fine in incognito mode.

`The page refreshes and yet the values are retained`.

```
if($window.localStorage.selectedServers !== undefined)
    selectedObj = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.selectedServers);
```

The problem is

**When I copy the Url and open in a new tab incognito itself,**

**The** `localStorage` **gets undefined.**

How to get rid of this issue? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: incognito mode will only keep/store the values temporarily, other 'tabs' will not have access.  Your history will disappear too. There is no workaround (that I know of)

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Storage (sessionStorage and localStorage) in private browsing mode (incognito)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042423/web-storage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-in-private-browsing-mode-incognit)

Comment: I use LocalStorage to keep user ID. After each refresh the incognito takes the user id from the notmal window and keeps it (doesen't sync with the normal window). Is this espected?

Answer (score 14):

> When I copy the Url and open in a new tab incognito itself,
>
> The localStorage gets undefined.

This is because as mentioned in the comments, incognito / private browsing windows will not retain local / session storage. Therefore when you open a new tab they are empty.