# Unable to login in Incognito mode with an iPhone (Chrome & Safari)

Tags: iphone, ajax, angular, authentication

We've noticed that when we try to logon to our application, using an iPhone with either Chrome or Safari, we get an authentication error.

Is there something special about making POST requests in Angular under these situations?

[UPDATE]: We can see that both the `OPTIONS` and `POST` are returned as being successful from our API, however, the UI continues to reject the response as being successful.

Comment: Are you using localstorage? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042423/web-storage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-in-private-browsing-mode-incognit

Comment: Yes, we are only after the user has authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to hint from @kai, it was, indeed, an issue that `LocalStorage` is not supported in Incognito mode. Need to have a fallback...