# Safari back-page (back button) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I am using the functionality below on a drop-down menu:**

- The drop down menu changes the used currency and therefore changes a
  price of items into that currency.
- When the drop-down is used, the code below also adds the    content from the "title" tag of the
  selected currency into a Text    Area (id="showTitle").
- [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is used because the    drop-down refreshes the
  page in a new currency and without    sessionStorage the text area on
  the new page would be empty.
- SessionStorage reloads the exact same content back into the text area
  everytime the page is refreshed. The only way to change the content
  is through use of the dropdown.

**So far all is well.
But now for the problem.**

With Safari (mac) as the browser:
if the user changes currency (let's say from Euro to US Dollars) and then uses the page back function of the browser, the price is changed back to the previous price in Euro, but the text area still shows "US Dollars", because it is loaded by sessionStorage. This only seems to occur with Safari. Has anybody got a way to solve this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList"  value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">$ € £</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById("showTitle");
    var savedValue = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");

    // See if we have an autosave value
    // (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
    if (savedValue) {
    // Restore the contents of the text field
        field.value = savedValue;
        //set dropdown to session value
        $('#currencyList option[title="'+ savedValue + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }

    // Listen for changes in the text field
    field.addEventListener("input", function() {
        // And save the results into the session storage object
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", this.value);
    });

   $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function(){
        //get text
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       //set field
       $(field).val(result);
       //set session storage item
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", result);
        //redirect
       window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    });

   });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860098/on-a-browser-sessionstorage-in-safaris-private-browsing-does-not-work-the-same

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. An interesting, but different issue. sessionStorage is working in Safari in non-private mode as described above. For the Safari private use situation, it does seem to give an issue so I read.

Comment: Just tested it in a Safari's private window and it still works as above.