# How to automatically test local session storage in Safari?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Safari Web Driver opens Safari browser instances in private mode.

Safari in private mode [does not allow JavaScript to save in local session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860098/on-a-browser-sessionstorage-in-safaris-private-browsing-does-not-work-the-same).

How do I automate Selenium tests for Safari for the application that uses local session storage?